# 1.9.0.1 Maintenance Mode

Tags: maintenance

Could someone please advise how to put 1.9.0.1 into Maintenance Mode? Or is this version not supported??  I found some instructions, however I don't have the option for Maintenance Mode for Ver 1.9.0.1 under System>Configuration>General

Comment: you can refer to [inchoo's blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/)

Answer (score 12):

Magento goes to maintenance mode when you create a file named **maintenance.flag** to your Magento home directory. This is how Magento handles it:

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an empty file with name maintenance.flag and just upload to the magento root directory

Answer (score 3):

Thats what I add to the index in order to be able to continue working from different IPs:

```
//EGS to show a maintenance page but be able to work
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// these are the IP's that are  allowed to view the site:
$allowed = array('111.111.111.111', '222.222.222.222');

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) { 
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed this tutorial http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-show-and-customize-magento-maintenance-mode-page to enable maintenance mode page in Magento, you need to create and upload `maintenance.flag` file to Magento root folder, however there are some more step for a good Maintenance mode like.

**Step 1:** Add exception during maintenance (allow specific IP to visit your site during maintenance). In `index.php`, add these lines

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$allowed = array('x.x.x.x','y.y.y.y');
```

**Step 2:** Edit maintenance mode page Edit maintenance mode page in `/errors/default/503.phtml` Remove wrap in `/errors/default/page.phtml`
Hope this helps.