# How to allow users to use specific controller actions (e.g. send form) in maintenance mode?

Tags: magento-1.8, maintenance

I created a custom maintenance page which appears after setting the **maintenance.flag** file.

The custom page has a few forms which I copied from the normal page, but they are not working.
Validation and date time picking works but If I send the form then I get `503 service unavailable` in the network analysis.

[image: 503]

I need the forms so that users can contact me and order stuff while the page is down.

It works without problems on the main page if the **maintenance.flag** is not set?

How can I allow the form on maintenance mode?

---

I tried to allow Mage by putting the following code at the top in `errors/default/page.phtml`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

But I still can't access any controller and get `503 Service Unavailable` in the developer console after attempting to submit the form.

---

Please describe the steps needed to allow specific controllers in maintenance mode. I try to let users subscribe to my newsletter and send the contact form, but they should not be allowed to shop.

---

EDIT: This question is obviously not a duplicate of ([1.9.0.1 Maintenance Mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24389/1-9-0-1-maintenance-mode)) because I don't ask how to put magento in maintenance mode. Learn english please @MagenX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1.9.0.1 Maintenance Mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24389/1-9-0-1-maintenance-mode)

Comment: @MagenX Please understand the question what he wants.

Comment: he wants to find `errors` folder, open `503.php` `processor.php` `503.phtml` and see how it works...

Comment: @MagenX, how is it a duplicate, I don't ask how to put magento in maintenance mode.

Comment: hmm, I just look at the accepted answer and the duplicate question, trying to understand who needs to learn English here ... do you need to read the same thing twice? lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your website is in maintenance mode then other codes will not work. If you check the index.php file in your magento root folder then you can find that magento will not run further when they find maintenance file in your root directory.

You can solve this by creating a custom php file in your magento root and include the Mage.php after that you can use the magento functions according to your requirement.

**METHOD 2**

You will get route name for the pages you want to consider by following code:

```
$routename = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

After that you need to put the condition like below:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && $routename != 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME') {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

You can get your routename(YOUR_ROUTE_NAME) by `echo $routename` just above the below code:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && $routename != 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME')
```

**METHOD 3:**

If *Method 2* was not working, then try:

```
$routename = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && $routename['path'] !== "/newsletter/subscriber/new/") { ... }
```

You can get your routename(YOUR_ROUTE_NAME) by `echo $routename['path']` just above the below code:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && $routename['path'] != 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME')
```

Comment: By "custom php file" do you mean a custom index.php? Or what file exactly do you mean sir?

Comment: Create abc.php on you magento root and include Mage.php with proper path. Now you can use this file as controller action and use contact us post action code here in your abc.php file.

Comment: And how does it work if I need it in **/errors/default/page.phtml** instead?

Comment: Put your conditions here in index.php(if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) ). You can put your controller actions here so that this will not allow to enter on that condition and page works perfectly for you.

Comment: How exactly can I put a controller action there, I don't know what you are talking about to be honest. An example would be great.

Comment: Can you check my updated answer? If any doubt let me know.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get **Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in "....index.php on line 168"**. Im not sure why. I added this code at the very top of *errors/default/page.phtml*: Line 1: `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';` Line 2:
`require_once $mageFilename;`
Line 3: `Mage::app("default");`. Im sure we are near to find the solution, please stick with me sir.

Comment: Where did you add code? Did you add the code on index.php just above the maintenance check code? Dont add anything to your page.phtml file.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the index.php above the line `if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {`

Comment: Ok, I removed the code which I posted in the comment above from the file `errors/default/page.phtml`. But the same error **Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in "....index.php on line 168** shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78735/discussion-between-black-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78766/discussion-between-black-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: @SukumarGorai Can we do this with Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

By default, You can not allow this. If you check Magento `index.php` file, you will found the below code:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

You can add your Custom condition here with Custom URL check.

Hope this help!!

Comment: **"You can add your Custom condition here with Custom URL check."**
Any example?

Comment: As we are applying condition before Magento library load. So you need to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to check the URl and apply condition accordingly.